# Check the proof of $\Bbb R$ as set of subsequential limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that there is a sequence in $\Bbb R$ that has all of $\Bbb R$ as its set of subsequential limits. Could someone help me check my proof? If it's not correct, could someone give a proof? Thanks.

Proof: Note that I already proved that every point of $\Bbb R$ is a limit point of $\Bbb Q$. Let $x$  be a limit point of $\Bbb Q$, then there is an $x_{t_1} \in B_1(x) \cap \Bbb Q$. Similarly, since $x$ is a limit point of $\Bbb Q$ there are infinitely many points of $\Bbb Q$ in $B_{1/2}(x)\cap \Bbb Q$. Choose $x_{t_2} \in B_{1/2}(x) \cap \Bbb Q$ where $t_2 \gt t_1$. Continue this process, we get a subsequence ($x_{t_k}$) converging to $x$.

Since every point of $\Bbb R$ is a limit point of $\Bbb Q$. Let ($p_n$) be sequence whose range is all of $\Bbb Q$, then we get that the set of subseqential limits of ($p_n$) is all of $\Bbb R$. Therefore, there is a sequence, i.e. ($p_n$), in $\Bbb R$ that has all of $\Bbb R$ as its set of subsequential limits.

Comment: Looks good. Perhaps it should have been mentioned explicitly that there **is** a sequence $(p_n)$ whose range is the rationals, i.e. that the rationals can be enumerated.

Comment: You have well answered your own question.

Comment: Consider that your "sketch."  Now write it up as elegantly as you can.  E.g., start here: "Let $(p_n)$ be a sequence whose range is all of $\mathbb Q$.  Let $x$ be any point in $\mathbb R$." Etc. using your argument, but applied to the sequence $p_n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get it now.